# Error al hacer pull que contiene un archivo modificado por mi en local

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Con Github Desktop intento hacer un pull, pero ese pull contiene un archivo que yo he modificado en mi ordenador, al intentar hacer el pull me salta el error siguiente, quería saber que ocurre si elijo la opcion Stash changes and continúe, ¿me sobrescribirá mi fichero local? ¿Qué es lo correcto que debería hacer en este caso?

[image: Error]

Comment: Hacer un Stash de tus cambios locales hace que llegue el archivo remoto y después podrás hacer unstash y volver a poner tus cambios

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿Cómo se hace el unstash? si el archivo que descargué y el que modifiqé en localhan cambiado una misma linea que pasaría en ese unstash? ¿Al hacer unstash puedo añadir mi código nuevo al archivo descargado?

Comment: @Alfabravo deberias escribir eso en una respuesta para votarlo. Para @DjEmilio84: `git stash save "guardando en el stash"`. Luego, cuando hayas hecho el pull: `git stash pop`. Si sale algún conflicto, lo resuelves y sigues con tu vida (en caso de que hubiera conflicto al hacer `git stash pop`, el item queda guardado en el stash, por cierto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es preguntarse ¿qué quieres hacer? Has hecho cambios en un fichero, pero el remoto también tiene cambios. ¿Cuál de los dos quieres que prevalezca? ¿O quieres que el resultado sea una mezcla de ambos? Según lo que elijas la respuesta de cómo hacerlo es diferente.

### Caso fácil

**Quiero descartar mis cambios y que prevalezcan los que vienen del pull**

Simplemente borra tu fichero local antes de hacer `pull`

### Caso intermedio

**Quiero descartar los cambios del remoto y que prevalezcan los míos**

Una opción sencilla es guardar una copia de tus cambios en otra carpeta. Después lo eliminas del repositorio local, haces el `pull` y luego lo sobreescribes otra vez con la copia de seguridad que tenías en la otra carpeta.

Finalmente harás un `git add` de ese fichero y `git commit` para que esta nueva versión (la tuya) forme parte del repositorio (tras lo cual puedes hacer `git push` para que sea visible en el remoto)

### Caso potencialmente difícil

**Quiero una mezcla de ambos y que la mezcla sea visible en la historia**

Comienza entonces por guardar en el repositorio local tus cambios, mediante `git add` y `git commit`. Después, al hacer el `git pull` git intentará mezclar los cambios remotos con los locales. Si no  lo consiguiera, te indicaría un conflicto y dejaría unas marcas en el fichero en cuestión.

Debes entonces editar ese fichero, revisar las marcas que te ha dejado (irán delimitadas entre un `<<<<<<` y  un `>>>>>>` y separadas por `======`, siendo una parte el cambio que hiciste tú y la otra el cambio que viene del remoto. Estas marcas pueden aparecer en varios lugares del fichero. Debes elegir cómo quieres que quede finalmente el fichero (borrando la parte que no te interese y dejando la que sí, o bien reescribiendo por completo los bloques en conflicto), y borrar las marcas.

Cuando el fichero haya quedado a tu gusto, le haces un `git add` y al hacer `git commit` continuará el "merge" que había quedado interrumpido. Se creará un nuevo commit de tipo "merge" (estos commits tienen dos "padres", uno con los cambios en la rama local y el otro con los cambios en la rama remota).

Finalmente harás un `git push` para subir al remoto los cambios de tu rama local junto con el commit-merge, para que el remoto quede ya igual que el local.

### Caso con stash

**Quiero una mezcla de ambos, pero no quiero un commit tipo merge, sino una historia lineal**.

En el fondo lo que quieres entonces es "arrepentirte de tus cambios", dejar que prevalezcan los remotos, pero después volver a hacer algunos de tus cambios encima de los que han venido. Para esto te puede servir el *stash*.

Cuando haces `git stash push`, el fichero con tus cambios se guarda temporalmente en otro lugar (oculto, gestionado por git), y la rama se retrocede a su última versión, para que el repositorio local quede como si no hubieras hecho esos cambios (algo así como lo hecho a mano en el caso 2). Así el `pull` no tiene problemas y deja la versión "remota".

Después harás un `git stash pop`, con lo que el fichero se recupera del almacén temporal donde git lo tenía, y se tratará de aplicar los cambios sobre el directorio de trabajo, encima de los que vinieron en el pull. Si todo va bien, te dejará una versión modificada que podrás ya guardar con
`git add/commit`. Pero en este caso sería un commit "normal" (con un solo padre en vez de dos), es decir, no un merge.

Si hubiera conflictos, se resolverían igual que en el caso 3, pero al final, una vez resueltos, el comando a dar para que todo finalice felizmente sería `git stash drop` (para eliminar del stash ese fichero temporalmente guardado).

Finalmente ya podrías hacer `git add/commmit` para guardar el fichero con la mezcla, y `git push` para subir ese nuevo commit al remoto.

Esto puede ser preferible si te gusta más tener una historia lineal del repositorio. En el fondo es como si los cambios que tú hiciste al fichero los hubieras hecho *después* y no antes del `pull`.

Comment: Esta respuesta debería ser marcada como canónica porque seguro habrá 98374298374 usuarios buscando esto mismo :)